# Conditional output minizinc

Tags: minizinc

I'm messing arround with minizinc and I'm trying to achieve a conditional output where, if an array element has value 'true', the program outputs information concerning these element's array indexes. This is what I have:

```
include "globals.mzn";
int: time=5;
int: n=3;
int: l=n*n;
array[1..4,0..time,1..l] of var bool: X;
constraint X[1,5,7]=true;
constraint X[2,5,3]=true;
constraint X[3,5,9]=true;
constraint X[4,5,7]=true;
solve satisfy;
```

I attempted to solve this problem using concat, like so:

```
output ["X_"++concat(["\(r)_\(t)_\(pos)" 
| pos in 1..l, r in 1..4, t in 0..time, where X[r,t,pos]==true])++"\n"];
```

However I am not allowed,
"MiniZinc: type error: no function or predicate with this signature found: `concat(array[int] of var opt string)'"

What I want is something like,

```
for pos in 1..l, r in 1..4, t in 0..time
 if X[r,t,pos]==true
  output ["X_\(r)_\(pos)_\(t)"]
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `fix(...)` around the decision variable in the `where` clause, e.g.

```
output ["X_"++concat(["\(r)_\(t)_\(pos)" 
| pos in 1..l, r in 1..4, t in 0..time, where fix(X[r,t,pos])==true])++"\n"];
```

`fix` is (often) needed when one use the actual values of decision variables, e.g. for comparing its values etc.

(The message about `var opt string` is perhaps misleading in this context.)